# Battery status API in macOS?

Tags: macos, battery

How can I read the status of the battery on my MacBookPro from my own application?

Googling has so far only revealed APIs for device drivers to handle power events - there's nothing about user-land processes accessing this information.

thanks.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You'll want to use IOKit for this, specifically the [IOPowerSources functions](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/iokit/iopowersources.h).  You can use `IOPSCopyPowerSourcesInfo()` to get a blob, and `IOPSCopyPowerSourcesList()` to then extract a CFArray out of that, listing the power sources. Then use `IOPSGetPowerSourceDescription()` to pull out a dictionary (see [IOPSKeys.h](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/iokit/iopskeys.h) for the contents of the dictionary).

Answer (score 78):

If you're looking for a quick way to query it from the command line, you'll find the pmset command helpful.  To query the battery status, specifically, use:

```
$ pmset -g batt
```

Comment: And this is particularly useful when using your Mac remotely via SSH. It's good to know if you need to sprint over to it to connect to the AC!

Comment: curious that this got so many upvotes, when it's explicitly an API call I was looking for (per the answer I accept)

Comment: Plausibly because the question title/tags doesn't distinguish between scripts/CLI and compiled contexts, so many (like myself) find a trivially wrappable answer more useful than an answer that requires me to drop into a specific compiled lang.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe help extracted text into script app

```
pmset -g batt | head -n 1 | cut -c19- | rev | cut -c 2- | rev
```

output

```
Battery Power
AC Power
```

Answer (score -2):

For Objective-C, this works to get the current percentage:

```
NSPipe *pipe = [NSPipe pipe];
NSFileHandle *file = pipe.fileHandleForReading;
NSTask *task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
task.launchPath = @"/usr/bin/pmset -g batt |  perl -ne ' print \"$1\n\" if /([0-9]+%)/'";
NSPipe *pipe = [NSPipe pipe];
task.standardOutput = pipe;
[task launch];
NSData *data = [pipe availableData];
```

Answer (score -3):

Look at the System Management Controller. I don't have my MBP handy, but I believe you need to look at smc.h