# How to programmatically get current battery level with Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, power-management

How can I get the current battery level using the Cocoa framework running with Leopard?

Currently I am getting it running a NSTask with:

```
pmset -g ps | grep -o -e [0-9]*% | sed -e 's/%//g'
```

But I think this is a clumsy way of doing this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe this question has been asked here before...
Here's some links:

[Battery status in OSX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/272552/battery-status-in-osx) (asked here before)

It limited my number of links because I'm new... but you should find more links there

Comment: Here is a full working example (for iPhone): http://blog.coriolis.ch/2009/02/14/reading-the-battery-level-programmatically/

Also, you could try here: http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Darwin/Reference/IOKit/IOPSKeys/index.html

Comment: I tried those, but I always get this error: http://pastebin.com/m3f72274c

Comment: I forgot to add IOKit.framework to my build path.
Now it's working.
Thanks