# How to get the battery life of mac os x macbooks programatically?

Tags: c, objective-c, macos, acpi

What I wanted to do is take a log on battery percentage. I know the equivalent in linux is sysctl(hw.acpi.battery.life). However when I went through the man of sysctl in mac os x I did not find the equivalent code to find it. Can some one point out how to do this using objective c. I can call sysctlbyname but that doesn't have this as input in its struct. Kindly help me please

Comment: Perhaps try adding an "objective-c" tag. I don't have the rep to edit yet unfortunately.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Battery status in OSX?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/272552/battery-status-in-osx)

Answer (score 21):

Try using [IOKit](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/DeviceDrivers/Conceptual/IOKitFundamentals/Families_Ref/Families_Ref.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP0000021-BABCCBIJ) and the [IOPowerSources](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/IOKit/IOPowerSources_h/index.html) functions. You can use [IOPSCopyPowerSourcesInfo()](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/IOKit/IOPowerSources_h/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/IOPSCopyPowerSourcesInfo) to get a blob, and [IOPSCopyPowerSourcesList()](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/IOKit/IOPowerSources_h/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/IOPSCopyPowerSourcesList) to then extract a CFArray out of that, listing the power sources. Finally you can use the [IOPSGetPowerSourceDescription()](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/IOKit/IOPowerSources_h/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/IOPSCopyPowerSourcesInfo) to grab the dictionary.

If you can use the command line, you can use the **[pmset](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/pmset.1.html)** command

Like so:

```
$ pmset -g
```

Comment: more specifically `pmset -g batt` show's the battery percentage and status.

Comment: @Dominic most of the links in your post are dead.

Answer (score 4):

you may use ioreg on the command line as well. For example:

```
ioreg -l -w0 |grep CurrentCapacity
```

gives you the current battery status, which may be compared to the max capacity:

```
ioreg -l -w0 |grep MaxCapacity
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to get some more info on battery status is to use NSTask to execute the system_profiler command with SPPowerDataType as the argument. On my Mac, it gives me the following results :

Battery Information:

```
  Model Information:
      Serial Number: W01396THJD3LA
      Manufacturer: SMP
      Device Name: bq20z451
      Pack Lot Code: 0
      PCB Lot Code: 0
      Firmware Version: 201
      Hardware Revision: 000a
      Cell Revision: 165
  Charge Information:
      Charge Remaining (mAh): 5013
      Fully Charged: Yes
      Charging: No
      Full Charge Capacity (mAh): 5086
  Health Information:
      Cycle Count: 72
      Condition: Normal
  Battery Installed: Yes
  Amperage (mA): -300
  Voltage (mV): 12303
```

To retrieve what you specifically, you could either parse the appropriate lines, or generate a plist with this command:

$ system_profiler SPPowerDataType -xml > BatteryInfo.plist

This would make it easier to retrieve the values, based on specific keys.