# How can I get the battery status of a magic mouse? (in %)

Tags: objective-c, battery, magic-mouse

how can I search for connected bluetooth/wireless devices e.g. a Magic Mouse? How can I get the % of the battery??

Please post me some code and explain it because I found somethings but I don't understand it really.

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this can be answered with the following:

[How to get the battery life of mac os x macbooks programatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432792/how-to-get-the-battery-life-of-mac-os-x-macbooks-programatically)

[Battery status in OSX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/272552/battery-status-in-osx)

[Getting iPhone's battery level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3276975/getting-iphones-battery-level)

[How to get the Battery Charge Level specifically in mWh (not percentage) for Mac (Cocoa or C)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3290395/how-to-get-the-battery-charge-level-specifically-in-mwh-not-percentage-for-mac)

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeviceDrivers/Reference/IOBluetoothUI/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000813

Hope it helps. This has been asked a few times as you can see.

**Update**

I know it's not Obj-C native api's but if you can't figure out IOPowerSources you can do this and parse the results

`ioreg -l | grep BatteryPercent`

Comment: The problem is now how can I get the status OF THE MOUSE. The 4. link helped me a little bit but how can i get the mouse?

Comment: @cocos2dbeginner I really think link 1 will provide what you need. I know it doesn't talk about it specifically but all the batter levels can be obtained through IOPowerSources. If I had a Mac I would write some code for you. There is also an alternative if you can live with spawning a process, I updated my answer with it.

Comment: Hi tried this:NSTask *server=[NSTask new];[server setLaunchPath:@"/bin/sh"]; [server setArguments:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"ioreg -c BNBMouseDevice | grep BatteryPercent"]]; NSPipe *outputPipe = [NSPipe pipe]; [server setStandardInput:[NSPipe pipe]]; [server setStandardOutput:outputPipe]; [server launch]; [server waitUntilExit]; [server release]; NSData *outputData = [[outputPipe fileHandleForReading] readDataToEndOfFile]; NSString *outputString = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:outputData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease]; but it says no such file or directory found. terminal works