# Get a battery status

Tags: ios

I'm making a game.

If phone's battery under 60%, the yield decrement is 60 - current battery%

So, My question is:
Can I get an information about battery % in iOS?

Comment: Your answer is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/272552/battery-status-in-osx

Comment: That answer is for OSX. question is tagged iOS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSArray *stateArray = @[@"Battery state is unknown", 
                        @"Battery is not plugged into a charging source", 
                        @"Battery is charging", 
                        @"Battery state is full"];

NSString *status = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Battery state: %@, Battery level: %0.2f%%",
                    stateArray[[UIDevice currentDevice].batteryState],
                    [UIDevice currentDevice].batteryLevel * 100];

NSLog(@"%@", status);
```

Answer (score 2):

iOS Developer Library

[UIDevice Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html)

You can download sample from [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/BatteryStatus/Introduction/Intro.html).

Answer (score 2):

If you wa t to get the Battery charge use this `[UIDevice currentDevice].batteryLevel`

It will return a float 0.0 - 1.0.