# MAC OSX- How do I get battery percentage status using python?

Tags: python, macos

I want to know if there is any library in python which can get me battery percentage remaining in Apple MACOSX(El'captain). I have researched a bit and found wmi for windows but could not find anything for MAC. Any leads appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A nice Python package [power](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/power) is available if you want to get it done quickly.

Also, you can try to execute the command line function `pmset -g batt` using Python [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module.

Finally, if you prefer, you can call the OS X native library `C` functions, see [Battery status in OSX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/272552/battery-status-in-osx).

Comment: Exactly what I was searching for.

Comment: I was looking for the bash command, thank you.